# SQL Server : picking entry with most recent date from table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am working with a SQL Server 2008 R2 table. I am trying to clean up the table. The tables contain a list of customer personal data and when the customer was last seen. I am trying to get a list of customers, but there are duplicates. Please consider my table below:

```
CustomerID  LastSeen    FirstName   LastName
--------------------------------------------
000030059   19971209    Jane        Doe  
000118444   20010210    Jane        Doe 
000000001   20100402    Marie       Dote
000000002   20121115    John        Glue
```

In this small sample, Jane Doe, has two entries. This would be considered a duplicate. I need to get most recent entry and not the other one. In this case, the entry with `LastSeen` value = '20010210'. I also need to get all the entries where there isn't a duplicate. The final result should look like this:

```
CustomerID  LastSeen    FirstName   LastName 
--------------------------------------------
000118444   20010210    Jane        Doe 
000000001   20100402    Marie       Dote
000000002   20121115    John        Glue
```

How can I do that in SQL Server with a T-SQL statement? I would prefer it being a single statement, but a script is fine. I am not sure where to start on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use a CTE with a "partitioned" `ROW_NUMBER` for this - something like this:

```
WITH SelectSingleRows AS
(
    SELECT
        CustomerID, LastSeen, FirstName, LastName,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY LastSeen DESC)
    FROM
        dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT
    CustomerID, LastSeen, FirstName, LastName
FROM
    SelectSingleRows
WHERE
    RowNum = 1
```

The CTE creates "partitions" (pockets of data) based on the `CustomerID`, and then numbers all the rows (for each `CustomerID`) based on the `ORDER BY` clause - here, I chose to sort in a descending fashion by `LastSeen` (hoping that this **IS** in fact a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column) - so the most recent entry will get a value of 1, then the next (if present) 2, and so on.

What you want is the most recent entry for each `CustomerID` - so you just select all those rows with a `RowNum = 1` from the CTE - and you're done,